# Opening html file from hard drive and doing xpath search on it

Tags: html, xpath

I have an html file on my HD that I want to do an xpath search on like you do when scraping a website.

I have used the following code to scrape from websites:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.website.com/')
if (response.status_code == 200):
    pagehtml = html.fromstring(response.text)
    for elt in pagehtml.xpath('//div[@class="content"]/ul/li/a'):
        print("**",'"',elt.text_content(),'"',"****", elt.attrib['href'])
```

Now this works well when getting something from a website, but how do I go about when the HTML file is on my HD. I have tried about 10 things and at the moment my code looks like this:

```
with open(r'website.html', 'rb') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    for elt in data.xpath('//h3/a'):
        print("**",'"',elt.text_content(),'"',"****", elt.attrib['href'])
```

I keep getting different errors and sometimes '_io.BufferedReader' errors, but I just don't get the code right.

Any suggestions? Regards

Comment: Using an XML parser seems like a bad idea, since HTML (even strict XHTML) is rarely valid XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
from lxml import html
pagehtml = html.parse('index.html')
for elt in pagehtml.xpath('//a'):
    print("**",'"',elt.text_content(),'"',"****", elt.attrib['href'])
```

This makes sure that the decoding of the file data is handled automatically.